# My WPF Application cannot locate resource 'Mainwindow.xaml'

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml

I have been working on a WPF application using vb.net and I've recently run into a problem.

When I build my code, the build is successful but when it comes to running the code the System.IO.IOexception throws an exception "Cannot locate resource ViewModel/ViewModel/Mainwindow.xaml"
The .Xaml windows are located in a folder called ViewModel hence I don't know where the other ViewModel/ViewModel... path is coming from, isn't it supposed to be viewModel/MainWindow.Xaml?
I have tried all possible solutions including cleaning up the Project but it doesn't seem to work.

The only solution that seems to work is if I change the StartupUri from 
`StartupUri = "ViewModel\MainWindow.Xaml"` TO `StartupUri = "...\MainWindow.xaml"` but I doubt if that is the right thing to do.

Comment: Did you try `.\ViewModel\MainWindow.xaml`? One question, why is a view located in a VM namespace? Doesn't make sence, since the VMs should not be aware of the views.

Comment: Yeah but it still does not work. I am not using MVVM The ViewModel Is just a name of a folder like any other, sorry for the confusion there.

Comment: Check your namespaces. The path is determined by the project namespace, not by the folder structure. Its possible you have a class in the folder `ViewModel` that has the namespace `MyApplication.ViewModel.ViewModel`

Comment: How come when i run the application using Expression Blend it runs just fine? Could anything be wrong with my visual studio?

Comment: I just discovered that there could have been some alteration in my xaml code... i don't know what it was but i moved the .xaml windows out of the folder, renamed the folder and put them back in and voila it worked! Thanks for your suggestions though.

Comment: I recently ran into an issue where a user had a different interface language set in his windows. After setting his interface language the app worked as excpected.

Answer (score 61):

Change the `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` to `StartupUri="FolderName/MainWindow.xaml"`

Solved my problem, when I moved my MainWindow to the View Folder

Comment: Thanks! Though it would be extra helpful if you specified exactly where this property is located. For me it was in App.xaml.

Comment: Is it me, or when you  move something in VB, it automatically gets updated everywhere in the project so you don't run into stupid little things like this that need micromanagement?

Answer (score 20):

In my case I needed to use pack URI syntax to set SrartUpUri property of my App.xaml file to point to a new location of my MainWindow.xaml, as so:

```
   <Application x:Class="TrafficLights.Controller.App"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                StartupUri="pack://application:,,,/View/MainWindow.xaml">
```

More on pack URIs here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx

Hope it helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 11):

This happened to me few times - always when I moved `MainWindow.xaml` to different folder and forgot to update `StartupUri` in `App.xaml`.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio has somehow renamed my `MainWindow.xaml` to `MainWindow(1).xaml`, so again I renamed it to `MainWindow.xaml`

Answer (score 1):

I renamed the `Mainwindow.xaml` file to `NameList.xaml` and had not updated the `App.xaml` file.  Once I did that `StartupUri="NameList.xaml"`, it was fine.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what has been answered here, you can use a more convenient URL formats that will prevent these kind of errors when you move App.xaml or MainWindow files to other folders. For example:

```
StartupUri="/Project;component/MainView/MainView.xaml"
```

If you specify the full path like above, then it doesn't matter where you move App.xaml, the location of MainView.xaml will remain correct (within a project). And if you move MainView.xaml then it is also clear how to update StartupUri.